# get highest number then print next number in new file

Tags: shell

**I have a file info.txt with pipe delimited, can you give me idea how to get the highest suffix and add entries on it based on the pattern?**

```
info="$HOME/info.txt"
echo "Input the pattern: "
read pattern

awk '/pattern/{ print $0 }' $info >> $HOME/temp1.$$
sed 's/MICRO_AU_FILE//g' $HOME/temp1.$$
##then count highest num but i think not good approach
##if got he highest num then print next number

for ACC_NUM in `cat acc`
  do
echo "$pattern-FILE$Highestsufix|server|$ACC_NUM*| >> $HOME/tempfile.$$
cat $HOME/tempfile.$$ >> $info
done
fi
```

info.txt

```
MICRO_AU-FILE01|serve|12345
MICRO_AU-FILE02|serve|23456
MICRO_AU-FILE04|serve|34534
MICRO_PH-FILE01|serve|56457
MICRO_PH-FILE02|serve|12345
MICRO_BN-FILE01|serve|78564
MICRO_BN-FILE03|serve|45267
```

acc

```
11111
22222
```

output: if my pattern is MICRO_AU

```
MICRO_AU-FILE01|serve|12345
MICRO_AU-FILE02|serve|23456
MICRO_AU-FILE04|serve|34534
MICRO_PL-FILE01|serve|56457
MICRO_PL-FILE02|serve|12345
MICRO_BN-FILE01|serve|78564
MICRO_BN-FILE03|serve|45267
MICRO_AU-FILE05|serve|11111
MICRO_AU-FILE06|serve|22222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract the suffixes, sort them ascending numerically, and take the highest one. If the input is as regular as in the example, this would be simply

```
HIGHEST_INDEX=$(cut -c 14,15|sort -nr|head -n 1)
```

If the structure of the lines can vary, you would have to adapt the number selector (`cut -c 14,15`) according to your tast.

UPDATE: I just see, that you have tagged your question with *shell* and not with *bash*, *zsh*, or *ksh*. If you need your program to run also on Bourne Shell, you have to use

```
HIGHEST_INDEX=`cut -c 14,15|sort -nr|head -n 1`
```

In general, it is best with this type of question, if you explicitly state, on which shell(s) your program should run. The more specific you are in this respect, the better solution we can suggest. For example, getting the next higher number (after HIGHEST_INDEX) is more complicated in Bourne shell as in the other ones.

Comment: I'm trying to use Bourne Shell, i tried the command and looks good but the position of digits is not always 14,15 which pattern varies. I will used similar approached as you mentioned. Thanks,